# What are azimuthal angles and colatitude?

Tags: r, plot

I'm using `persp` and trying to change the viewing angle. The relevant parameters are `theta` and `phi` but unfortunately the docs are quite cryptic (`?persp`):

> `theta`, `phi`: angles defining the viewing direction. `theta` gives the azimuthal direction and `phi` the colatitude.

In the **Details** section, they go into some more circular explanation:

> The surface is... viewed by looking at the origin from a direction defined by `theta` and `phi`. If `theta` and `phi` are both zero the viewing direction is directly down the negative y axis. Changing `theta` will vary the azimuth and changing `phi` the colatitude.

It's been quite some time since I took three-dimensional calculus to remember all the names used for spherical coordinates, and anyway even then the angles were never referred to as "azimuthal" or "colatitude", but instead simply by their Greek letters.

The closest I can guess is from this graph from Wikipedia about spherical coordinates:

[image: A plot taken from Wikipedia. It's a 3D plot (three axes -- X, Y, and Z). It shows an arbitrary point in the 1st (all X,Y,Z positive) quadrant, labeled (r, theta, phi). theta is labeled as the angle between the vertical Z axis and the segment 'r' connecting the origin to the point. phi is labeled as the angle between the X axis and the projection of the point onto the XY plane.]

Are these the same `theta` and `phi` referred to in the docs? I know math notation is nothing if not vexingly inconsistent across authors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colatitude - "flip" the 3d cube back such that X is up and Z is front. It's a matter of .. perspective =^_^=

Comment: @user2864740 colatitude = **co**mplement of **latitude** makes sense :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, the easiest way to figure this out (usually easier than going and [looking at the code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7b3b979f65e74e5e5a6c0757a49b9f300c374734/src/library/graphics/src/plot3d.c), IMO: if you want, see `XRotate` and `ZRotate` at the link) is to experiment.

As you can see here, `theta` rotates around the Z-axis and `phi` rotates around the X-axis, so `phi=90` corresponds to a straight-overhead view ... i.e. the opposite of the notation you have shown above.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Code for reproduction:

```
x<-seq(0,2,len=11)
y<-seq(0,2,len=11)
z<-outer(x,y,function(x,y){
  (x>1&y<=1)*2+(x<=1&y>1)*1+(x>1&y>1)*(1-(x-1)*(y-1))})

colors<-c(rep(rep(c("red","blue"),c(5,5)),5),
          rep(rep(c("yellow","green"),c(5,5)),5))

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
persp(x,y,z,theta=0,phi=30,col=colors,main="Theta: 0")
persp(x,y,z,theta=60,phi=30,col=colors,main="Theta: 60")
persp(x,y,z,theta=120,phi=30,col=colors,main="Theta: 120")
persp(x,y,z,phi=0,col=colors,main="Phi: 0")
persp(x,y,z,phi=30,col=colors,main="Phi: 30")
persp(x,y,z,phi=60,col=colors,main="Phi: 60")
```

Comment: Thanks, of course this is the way to go but I was hitting writer's block on making a simple example to play with. I hope you don't mind that I've updated the plot to something that's hopefully more illustrative (colors & sharp differentiation among quadrants)